# How to erase Drawing Lines on UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, cgcontext

I drew a line on `UIView`. It's working properly. I did the same thing as described here : [question]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595446/drawing-an-image-is-completely-out

And now I need to erase those lines. Erase means after I move my finger on the touch screen I need to erase it. Just like an eraser. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to erase the whole line when the user touches it, than i don't know how you can achieve that, but if you are asking to erase the part of the line were the user touches, than you can draw a line of the color the view that you are using to draw the line on to in that way you will get the effect of an eraser.

Comment: Their is a background image too. It's on bottom UIView. Im drawing a line on second view. It's created on top of first view. So ''

Comment: I think you can draw a line with alpha value as 0 and that intersects the line below it. Have you tried that or not.

Comment: CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
            
   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
   CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        }
[erasImage drawAtPoint:lastPoint blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:eraseSpeed];
   
   
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect( context, rect );

    }
  
 imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    
}`

Comment: this is my erasing option code.. 
but its run on - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method,

So here is the place that load the initial value to my back ground;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
[UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect( context, rect );

I need to pass my 

drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

to their? did you get what i told? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` (UIView) to set the rectangle of the line as invalid. Only this rectangle will be redrawn until the next drawing cycle.

Make sure you have a flag in the `drawRect:` method you can ask for, that identifies whether the line should be drawn or not.

Comment: [link](http://craigcoded.com/2010/12/08/erase-top-uiview-to-reveal-content-underneath/)

Theck that link. 
and 

Check this code also;

 // First time in, we start with a solid color
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, maskColor.CGColor );
 CGContextFillRect( context, rect )

If I load my drawing here then its working cool. How can I load my drawing to here.